# Missing or insufficient permissions firestore database rules

Tags: firebase, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore, rules

I'm self studying firestore and I could not figure out a way to only allow a user to update, delete or read only the collections added by them.

This is the structure I'm using:
[image: firebase database screenshot]

I use firebase auth for user handing. I save the `currentUser.uid` as `user_id` in the database for each collection.

These are the rules I'm using

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /tasks{
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
```

When I try to read/get the data I get `Missing or insufficient permissions` error.

I'm using the web api (JavaScript) for firestore. This is the code I'm using to read data.

```
function read() {

    db.collection("tasks").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var newLI = document.createElement('li');

            newLI.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.data().task));

            dataList.appendChild(newLI);

        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error was in my JavaScript I was getting all without filtering by user

```js
function read() {
    let taskColletion = db.collection("tasks");

    taskColletion.where("user_id", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var newLI = document.createElement('li');

            newLI.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.data().task));

            dataList.appendChild(newLI);
        });
        
    });

}
```

Comment: I found the same. The security rule filter must be added to the where clause. Even in cases where you wouldn't have the where clause otherwise (such as query a hierarchical sub-collection with a specific parent document id that all the children are known to match the where clause)

Comment: To elaborate on the root cause behind why your answer is correct [Rules are not Filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters)

> You cannot write a query for all the documents in a collection and expect Cloud Firestore to return only the documents that the current client has permission to access.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually explained on the [Firestore Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication)(I recommend reading it).

You're missing a wildcard after `/tasks`:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tasks/{task} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already it but it's still giving me the `Missing or insufficient permissions`